# NoSuchMethodError:The method '[]' was called on null Tried calling :[]("a")

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-animation, flutter-test

I am trying to build a quizz app in flutter using JSON file so first I want to load question in this widget then call the quize page widget . THIS CODE WORKS MOST OF THE TIME FINE BUT SOMETIMES IT GAVE THIS ERROR NOT ALL THE TIME
Example code:

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
// TODO: implement build
// this function is called before the build so that
// the string assettoload is avialable to the DefaultAssetBuilder
setasset();
// and now we return the FutureBuilder to load and decode JSON
return FutureBuilder(
  future: DefaultAssetBundle.of(context).loadString(assettoload, cache: true),
  builder: (context , snapshot){
    List mydata = json.decode( snapshot.data.toString());
    if(mydata==null){
      return Scaffold(
          body: Center(
          child: Text(
          "Loading",
           ),
         ),
      );
    }
    else{
      return  quizpage(mydata: mydata);//this line giving me the error
    }
  }
);
```

Comment: What error are you getting now

Comment: can you add what is value of mydata in else and also add what is quizpage ?

Comment: NoSuchMethodError:The method ' [ ] ' was called on null. Reciever :null Tried Calling: [ ] ("a") @RavindraKushwaha

Comment: Basically my data is JSON file having question and answer . [
    {
        "1": "What Will Be The Output Of the Following Code ?\na = \"p\" * 3\nprint(a)",

    },
    {
        "1": {
            "a": "pp",
            "b": "ppp",
            "c": "3p",
            "d": "p3"
        }
    },
    {
        "1": "ppp",

    }
]

Answer (score 0):

```
List mydata = new List();
 mydata = json.decode( snapshot.data.toString());
```

Use This and Now Check it will work now